# How to build when there's no makefile or installation script using meson (?)

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, compiling, git

I am trying to install Dconf Editor.

I created a directory, switched to it and then ran

```
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dconf-editor.git
```

I looked for an installation script, there isn't one but there is a `README.md` file. However the contents of the file are:

```
 # Dconf-Editor

A GSettings editor for GNOME.

## Useful links

- Homepage: <https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DconfEditor>
- Report issues: <https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dconf-editor/issues/>
- Translate: <https://wiki.gnome.org/TranslationProject>
- Code of Conduct: <https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dconf-editor/blob/master/code-of-conduct.md
```

When I try to run `make` it just says that there is no make file. There is a file called `meson.build` so I installed `meson` and attempted to use it

```
$ sudo meson builddir && cd builddir
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.2
Source dir: /home/eddie/build/dconf-editor
Build dir: /home/eddie/build/dconf-editor/builddir
Build type: native build
Project name: dconf-editor
Project version: 3.38.2

meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not execute Vala compiler "valac"`
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Why don't you install it by `sudo apt install dconf-editor`?

Comment: I didn't realize that was a thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to compile it. You can install it by

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

But the `Could not execute Vala compiler "valac"` means that you need to install `valac` if you really want to compile it from source.